# Can someone provide an example situation where I would need to use socket.io-redis?

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

**From the socket.io docs [http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#sending-messages-from-the-outside-world] I read the following but I can't seem to connect it to any use case in my head:**

> Sending messages from the outside-world In some cases, you might want
>   to emit events to sockets in Socket.IO namespaces / rooms from outside
>   the context of your Socket.IO processes.
>
> There’s several ways to tackle this problem, like implementing your
>   own channel to send messages into the process.
>
> To facilitate this use case, we created two modules:
>
> ```
> socket.io-redis
> socket.io-emitter
> ```
>
> By implementing the Redis Adapter:
>
> ```
> var io = require('socket.io')(3000);
> var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
> io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));
> you can then emit messages from any other process to any channel
>
> var io = require('socket.io-emitter')();
> setInterval(function(){
>   io.emit('time', new Date);
> }, 5000);
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a cluster of servers and want to talk to clients that are connected to different instances, you'll need a common storage -- that's when you use Redis.

You are also mentioning io-emitter, which is a way for other processes to post messages to your clients. For example, if a worker needs to emit messages to your clients, it can use io-emitter. Redis is the common glue for sharing messages across different processes/servers.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. But what do you mean by " io-emitter, which is a way for other processes to post messages to your clients" ? Are these other processes on a single server ?

Comment: No. You might have a worker running on a separate node.js process, for example (usual cases are video encoders that run for a long time) and maybe you want them to send messages regarding progress). They may use io-emitter for that, like emitting to a certain room. The io-emitter instance on the worker will point to the central Redis server and everyone on that room will receive messages from your worker.

Answer (score 1):

The module is needed only when you want to spread your solution to multiple solutions or node processes. Through the redis adapter the multiple servers could broadcast to other clients.

Basically when you have two servers each running their own server. Server A has three clients. Server B has two different clients. These two servers does not share any client information so you won't be able to broadcast to all the users message. The adapter gives you ability to connect these different servers into one(using redis), so you would be able to broadcast to all the users.

Also good presentation to look about socket.io and redis http://www.slideshare.net/YorkTsai/jsdc2013-28389880.

Comment: Where would the redis reside ? Do the servers connect to the redis server using an address?

Comment: basically, you need a separate instance of redis running somewhere(as a service or in your server), connection to redis through the address ```redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 })```

Comment: Thanks that helps.